# NXClient missing font on Debian

Tags: windows, debian, freenx, nomachine, debian-wheezy

I am able to connect successfully from my Windows 7 box to Debian(testing) but all the fonts on desktop and menus are missing.

I installed NXClient, Node and server by downloading the deb packages directly from nomachine.com website.

I tried copying the font files from debian box to the windows box, read this could help but no difference.

Anyone come across this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by disabling the render extension under 'Configure...'.

Check 'Use custom settings', select 'Settings...', then check 'Disable the render extension'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Using Windows 7, NXClient would connect to Debian Wheezy server, but only the desktop wallpaper was visible, or at best I could see the icons in the navigation bar but no text visible in the terminal window. The solution that worked for me is as follows:

1. Open the NX client on your Windows machine
2. Configure button
3. In Display Area section of the menu – Use Custom Settings
4. Settings button
5. Check last box – disable emulation of shared pixmaps
6. Save

should work.